# Loops for assigning/calculating student grade (c++)

Tags: c++, loops, average, calculator

I'm sort of having a hard time with my program, and I would really appreciate any help. Forgive me for my really bad code, I'm new.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
//functions
string getFirstName();
string getLastName();
int getScores();
double calculateSum(double sum, double score);
double calculateAvg(double avg, double sum);
char calculateGrade(double score, char grade);
void displayResults(string firstname, string lastname, double avg, char 
grade);

int main(){
//variables
string firstname;
string lastname;
int score;
double sum;
double avg;
char grade;
//functions and parameters
firstname = getFirstName();
lastname = getLastName();
score = getScores();
sum = calculateSum(sum, score);
avg = calculateAvg(avg, sum);
grade = calculateGrade(score, grade);
displayResults(firstname,lastname,avg,grade);


while (true)
{
firstname = getFirstName();
cin >> firstname; 
if (firstname == "done")break;
lastname = getLastName();
cin >> lastname;
sum=0.0;

  for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        double score;
     cin >> score;
     sum - calculateSum(sum, score);
      sum+=score;
      //sum = sum+score;
    }
     avg = calculateAvg(avg, sum);
  avg = sum/10.0;
    displayResults(firstname,lastname,avg,grade);
 }
return 0; 
}

string getFirstName()
{
string firstname;
cout<<"Enter first name: " << endl;
cin >>firstname;
return firstname;
}

string getLastName()
{
string lastname;
cout<<"Enter last name: ";
cin >>lastname;
return lastname;
}

int getScores()
{
int score;
cout <<"Input score: ";
cin >>score;
return score;
}

double calculateSum(double sum, double score)
{
sum+=score;
return sum;
}

double calculateAvg(double avg, double sum)
{
avg = sum/10.0;
return avg;
}

char calculateGrade(double score, char grade)
{

if (score >= 90) 
grade = 'A';
else if (score >=80) 
grade = 'B';
else if (score >=70)
grade = 'C';
else if (score >=60) 
grade = 'D';
else 
grade = 'F';
return grade;
}


void displayResults(string firstname, string lastname, double avg, char 
grade)
{
cout<<firstname<< lastname<<": "<<avg << grade;
}
```

I don't really understand loops, or how they work, so what I have written down for my loop was just given to us by our professor, so if anyone could please explain/dissect it then I would really appreciate it! I want to know how to do this, not just have answers handed to me.

So, I'm not sure why my program won't properly execute. I've listed the call functions and all of the functions seem to be correct. My loops are inside of the main as well, but I don't know why they're not working. Also, when I run it, I don't have any errors.

It seems to be stuck on the enter first name and enter last name part, but I'm not sure why.Again, I'd really appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: firstname = getFirstName();
cin >> firstname; getFirstName does already capture input for firstname. there are similar occurrances in your code. Moreover, sum - calculateSum(sum, score); does nothing at all, it substract from sum calculateSum(sum, score). Your code has many mistakes. As @GalloCedrone suggested you should study and use debugging tools.

Comment: If you don't want the solution handed to you and to work on it you can consider to try to debug. A lot of tools are available, but the most straightforward since you are a beginner is to print 1,2,3,4,5,6 in different parts of the code till you really understand which function is not behaving as expected. Then you work on that function.

Comment: Unless you've formatted this incorrectly, at the beginning of your `main` you call many of your functions with uninitialized variables (resulting in undefined behavior). At best this is bad practice, at worst it could break your entire program.

Comment: If you want to learn loops, look them up in your course material, and try writing *the simplest program you can think of that uses a loop*. Do NOT write a program this big that relies on a structure you don't understand.

Comment: Please mark my solution as accepted answer if you found it helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You code was full of bugs, but I will lead you through it step by step.

First things first, we will need to check what each function does :

1- `string getFirstName();` Prompt the user to enter his/her first name. **Working**

2- `string getLastName();` Prompt the user to enter his/her last name. **Working**

3- `int getScores();` Prompt the user to enter his/her score. **Working**

4- `double calculateSum(double sum, double score);` Adds both the sum and the score. What you did in your implementation of the function :

```
{
sum+=score;
return sum;
}
```

Will only be valid if you pass variable `sum` by reference. There is no need to get into this now. An easier way to do it is to do so :

```
{
double add = sum + score;
return add;
}
```

Next up :

5- `double calculateAvg(double avg, double sum);` Divides `sum` by `10` to get the average, there's no need to pass `avg` as a parameter as that's what we are going to return.

The function should be written as `double calculateAvg(double sum);`

6- Same goes `char calculateGrade(double score, char grade);`. There's no need to pass `grade`. It will be written as`char calculateGrade(double score);`.

7- Last one : `void displayResults(string firstname, string lastname, double avg, char grade);` **Working**

---

Ok, now to the `main()` function :
You'll need to declare all of your variables like so

```
string firstname;
string lastname;
double score;
double sum ;
double avg ;
char grade;
```

No need to use our functions here, we are going to use them inside our `while` loop.

Into the `while` loop :

- There's no need to use `cin>>` with any of variables cause that's what our functions is doing for us.
- When the user enters `done` as his/her first name exit the loop.
- Else, create a `for` loop that iterates 10 times asking the user to input his/her score, add this score to the sum and then after the `for` loop ends calculate both the `average` and the `grade` and print them out.

---

The final working version of your code should look like this, if you still have any further questions don't hesitate to ask.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;
//functions
string getFirstName();
string getLastName();
int getScores();
double calculateSum(double sum, double score);
double calculateAvg(double sum);
char calculateGrade(double score);
void displayResults(string firstname, string lastname, double avg, char grade);

int main(){
//variables
string firstname;
string lastname;
double score;
double sum ;
double avg ;
char grade;

while (true)
{
    firstname = getFirstName();
    if (firstname == "done")
        break;
    lastname = getLastName();
    sum=0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        {
         score = getScores();
         sum = calculateSum(sum, score); //sum = sum+score;
        }
         avg = calculateAvg(sum);
        grade = calculateGrade(avg);
        displayResults(firstname,lastname,avg,grade);
     }
    return 0; 
}

string getFirstName()
{
string firstname;
cout<<"Enter first name: ";
cin >>firstname;
return firstname;
}

string getLastName()
{
string lastname;
cout<<"Enter last name: ";
cin >>lastname;
return lastname;
}

int getScores()
{
int score;
cout <<"Input score: ";
cin >>score;
return score;
}

double calculateSum(double sum, double score)
{
int add = sum + score;
return add;
}

double calculateAvg(double sum)
{
double avg = sum/10.0;
return avg;
}

char calculateGrade(double score)
{
char grade;
if (score >= 90) 
grade = 'A';
else if (score >=80) 
grade = 'B';
else if (score >=70)
grade = 'C';
else if (score >=60) 
grade = 'D';
else 
grade = 'F';
return grade;
}


void displayResults(string firstname, string lastname, double avg, char grade)
{
cout<<firstname<< lastname<<" - Average : "<<avg << " - Grade : "<< grade<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop is just a way of executing the same piece of code over and over again. By putting code in a loop, you do not have to copy and paste it. Any variable changes which happen during one run through a loop are still present during the next.

In your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
{ 
   ...
}
```

is your loop. The "..." is code which will be executed over and over.

The big question which needs to be asked with a loop is: How does a loop know how many times to run your code before it exits?

This is what the:

```
int i = 0; i<10; i++
```

is about. Though it looks strange it is actually 3 separate commands. The commands are separated by the semi-colon ';'

1. int i=0
2. i<10
3. i++

Command (1) initialize the loop. You are simply setting the variable i, which an integer, to 0.

Command (2) condition to continue looping. If command (2) is *true* then the loop will execute (and execute again). Your code is saying execute the loop whilst i is less than 10.

Command (3) calculations executed once per loop. We know in Command (1) that you set i to 0. We know in Command (2) that the loop will run while i is less than 10. 0 is less than 10, so the loop will execute... forever. We don't want this, so during Command (3) we increase i. We count the number of times we run the loop.

So your loop will run 10 times in a row, the code inside it and then exit.